# .NET creating an IEnumerator on top of "GetEnumerator()" method from another class

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerator

I'm trying to create an `IEnumerator` based on the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` as you can see below. My enumerator works on top of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` by using LINQ `.Select` to convert the `FileInfo` into a specialized class `MyFile`.

```
    struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<MyFile>
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IEnumerator<MyFile>> enumerator;

        public Enumerator(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            enumerator = new Lazy<IEnumerator<MyFile>>(() =>
            {
                return directory
                .EnumerateFiles($"*{MyFile.Extension}", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
                .Select(MyFile.Read)
                .GetEnumerator();
            });
        }

        WalFile IEnumerator<MyFile>.Current => enumerator.Value.Current;
        object IEnumerator.Current => enumerator.Value.Current;
        void IDisposable.Dispose() => enumerator.Value.Dispose();
        bool IEnumerator.MoveNext() => enumerator.Value.MoveNext();
        void IEnumerator.Reset() => enumerator.Value.Reset();
    }
```

But it only works when I iterate once. If I iterate the enumerator twice, the 2nd time it's empty. Even removing the `Lazy`, it doesn't change the result.

This `IEnumerator` is used in another class such as `MyFileCollection : IEnumerable<MyFile>`, where I implement `IEnumerable` with the specialized `Enumerator` class above.

Any insights to be this right?

**UPDATE**:
Since people started asking why I'm doing this. This question is not about the design. I didn't show every class or the design around it, because I wanted to simplify the question to get an answer of how to use `IEnumerator` class.

```
public interface ILocalRepository : IEnumerable<MyFile>
{
    DirectoryInfo Directory { get; }
    MyFile? Get(string name);
    MyFile Create(MyVersion script);
    Task<MyFile> DownloadLatestAsync(IScriptResource resource, string name, CancellationToken cancellation);
    Task<MyFile> DownloadAsync(IScriptResource resource, string name, MyVersion version, CancellationToken cancellation);
    void Delete(string name);
}

class LocalFileRepository : ILocalRepository
{
    protected readonly DirectoryInfo directory;
    private readonly Enumerator enumerator;

    public LocalFileRepository(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        this.directory = directory;
        enumerator = new Enumerator(directory);
    }

    DirectoryInfo ILocalRepository.Directory => directory;

    IEnumerator<MyFile> IEnumerable<MyFile>.GetEnumerator() => enumerator;
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => enumerator;
    //implementation hidden...
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`? I haven't done that since `yield return` was introduced. `yield return` makes doing this soooo easy

Comment: Works as designed, but your design is flawed. The root of the issue is that an instance of this class represents just one enumeration. You would need to create a second instance of it to enumerate a second time.

Comment: It's overkll, really. All you need is a method, the body of which is what you have initializing the `Lazy<T>` above. Call that method each time you need to enumerate.

Comment: Also the use of Lazy seems unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't know I have to create new instances of the `Enumerator` everytime I need to enumerate the collection. In that case, yeah, the `Enumerator` is overkill since I just need to write `public IEnumerator<MyFile> GetEnumerator() => directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Select(...)`.

Comment: If your underlying sequence is repeatable (like an array), you could use IEnumerator's Reset() method. Otherwise, once you have used up the sequence, you can't enumerate it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing a custom enumerator, you could just use the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<MyFile> EnumerateFiles(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
  return directory
    .EnumerateFiles($"*{MyFile.Extension}", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
    .Select(MyFile.Read);
}
```

This is much simpler than creating an enumerator from scratch; if you need the code in various places, you can implement it in a helper class that you inject into the classes that rely on it. This is especially a good way if you need to mock the code in unit tests. If this does not matter, you can also make it a static helper method or an extension method to `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: why not using an `IEnumerator` if I need the code in multiple places? why use a "helper class"? just wondering your thoughts on why a "helper static class" is better than an `IEnumerator`, which I thought makes sense for reusing the logic.

Comment: The best way would be a helper class that you inject into other classes. This way, you can exchange it later or mock it in tests. If you compare the samples, the code for a method is much simpler than creating an enumerator - that's why I'd go with a method, whether it is in a static helper class or as a class that you inject into other classes.

Comment: Since I thought I could reuse the same instance of my custom `Enumerator`, I designed like that, but giving a 2nd thought and based on the feedback I got here, it was indeed useless. When implementing `IEnumerable<MyFile>` in my `LocalFileRepository`, I just went with `public IEnumerator<MyFile> GetEnumerator() => directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Select(...)`